# Python redis smemebers is always returning shuffeled set

Tags: python, redis

When I try to get members of a set using python smembers function it is always returning shuffled data. And every call to smembers returns random data. However when I do a smembers through redis cli, it always returns correct sorted data from that set.

```
print(redis_con.smembers('alpha'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`redis-py` returns a [Python set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) which is per default unordered:

```
>>> import redis
>>> con = redis.Redis('localhost', 6666)
>>> rSet = con.smembers('xyz')
>>> print(type(rSet))
<class 'set'>
```

You would need to [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to) the set yourself:

```
rSetSorted = sorted(rSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis set is unordered, so the result of `smembers` are NOT sorted. That's a expected behavior. If you want to have sorted result, you need to sort it manually.